# Is the unitary matrix group path-connected?

Tags: lie-groups

Is the group $\mathcal{U} (n)$ of all $n\times n$ unitary matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ a (local) path-connected space?

If so, what are the connected components of the unitary matrix group $\mathcal{U}(n)$? Is the number of components finite? What is the representative for each component? Is each components closed in norm topology?

Comment: This is explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group . I voted to close as "too localized".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every matrix Lie group is a smooth manifold, hence it is path-connected if and only if it is connected.
And  $U(n)$ is compact and connected as a topological space (any unitary matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix, this gives a path from it to the identity). It is not simply-connected, though.
We have $\pi_1(U(n))\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry, a late question. I can see that the U(n) is path-connected, however, since U(n) is not simply connected as you clearly pointed out. Does that mean the continuous deformation of the path from A to Identity is not homotopic?